# How to accept n number of inputs based on an integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently working on a problem where I have to input one number say n and based on that I need to receive n lines with one number in each. How do I split the input number into several input lines?

Comment: The answer to this problem could have been found with little to no research. Please show your efforts in solving the problem before asking questions. The same applies to the answer below: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You loop:

```
nr = int(input("How many? Use a number, else crash"))

inputvalues = []
for _ in range(nr):
    inputvalues.append(int(input("Input another number")))
```

and store the other inputs into a list.

```
print(inputvalues)  # [1,2,3,4,5] after first input of 5 and input of 1,2,3,4,5
```

Further readings:

- [lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)
- [int()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)
- [range()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)
- [for loops](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)

Comment: Thank you Patrick. I will go through the further reading as well.